# Google Map Direction API issue in cordova ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am working in Cordova, in my application I am using Google Map when I click on direction link it shows the direction from other place instead of showing from current location to destination. In android it shows the direction from current location to destination, this issue is not there but in iPhone 7(v-11.3.1) and iPad retina(v-13.2) I am getting this issue but in iPhone 5(v-10.3.4) it is working.

Another thing is when I open Google Map using google map URL for first time (if google map is not running in background) direction will not show. If google map is running in background then direction will show properly this issue is not in android but in iOS I am getting this issue

I used all these URL for Google Map Direction where it will auto fill my current location but it shows other location instead of current location

```
var mapLocationUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=" + lat + "," + lng;
var mapLocationUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Current+Location&destination=" + dLat + "," + dLong + "&travelmode=driving";
var mapLocationUrl = "https://maps.google.com/maps?origin=My+Location&daddr=" + lat + "," + long;
var mapLocationUrl = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=current location&daddr=" + lat + "," long;
var mapLocationUrl = "maps://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + lat + "," + long + "&amp;ll=";
var mapLocationUrl = "https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + lat + "," + lng;

window.open(encodeURI(mapLocationUrl), '_self', 'location=yes');
```

Can anybody tell me why this happens?. is there any problem using Google Map in iPhone?

Comment: why the domain for map apis is `https://www.google.com/maps/....`. It should be `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?....`

Comment: Please check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58509024/11742502