# Why is Google Maps failing to resolve the directions when opening the App with a iOS URL Schema?

Tags: ios, react-native, google-maps, react-native-ios, google-maps-urls

I'm developing a React Native application that links out to Google Maps and Apple Maps to provide Turn by Turn navigation.

We've had some interest from Users of being able to use Google Maps on iOS due to the availability of Offline Maps.

When attempting to Link out to Google Maps (using the React Native Linking API) the Google Maps app opens fine. However, the App isn't resolving the Route, and spins forever.

If I go back to *my* App, leaving Google Maps open, and click the Button that Links out to Google Maps again, it opens Google Maps and resolves almost straight away. As an additional kick in the teeth, it works when Offline and using the Offline Maps feature perfectly.

Below is the link I'm trying to use, where destination is usually a latlong but can be an address.

`comgooglemapsurl://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=${destination}&nav=1`

Bonus points:

If you can tell me how start the navigation automagically using the non url Schema; the following does not work with nav=1 at the end:

`comgooglemaps://?f=d&daddr=${destination}&nav=1`

[image: Google Maps Failing to Resolve]

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58509024/11742502